# Mocha tests can't connect to postgres database, using knex

Tags: postgresql, mocha.js, knex.js

I am trying to implement some integration tests using mocha for functions that interact with a postgres database through knex, in a nodejs express app.
The functions work outside of mocha - I can start the app in node or nodemon, submit requests through Postman, retrieve records from the database, add new records, etc. But when I try to test the code through mocha, I get errors like the following for any functions that try to access the database:

```
 select * from "item" where "user_id" = $1 - relation "item" does not exist
```

The environment variable for the database connection is set to connect to the right database; when I manually test the app end-to-end, everything works; I get data back from the database.

I've included what I think are the relevant code snippets below: the test script for one of the tests that won't work, the function I'm trying to test, and the modules that that function relies on.

TEST SCRIPT

```
const Item = require('../db/item');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

// set up the middleware
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var should = require('chai').should() 

describe('Item.getByUser', function() {
  contex`enter code here`t('With valid id', function() {
    const item_id = 1;
    const expectedResult = "Canoe";
    it('should return items', function() {
      return Item
      .getByUser(item_id)
      .then(items => {
        items[0].name.should.equal(expectedResult);
        });    
      });  
    });
```

SNIPPET FROM THE ITEM.GETBYUSER FUNCTION:

```
const knex = require('./connection');

module.exports = {

  getByUser: function(id) {
    return knex('item').where('user_id', id);
  },
```

SNIPPET FROM THE CONNECTION MODULE:

```
require('dotenv-safe').config();
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('../knexfile')[environment];
module.exports = require('knex')(config);
```

SNIPPET FROM THE KNEXFILE MODULE:

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
  },
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL 
  }

};
```

The error message I get for the above test is:

```
1) Item.getByUser
       With valid id
         should return items:
     select * from "item" where "user_id" = $1 - relation "item" does not exist
  error: relation "item" does not exist
      at Connection.parseE (node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:567:11)
      at Connection.parseMessage (node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:391:17)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's looking like this was in fact related to the environment variable for the database in some way I can't quite figure out. Although I had the database connection set to 'postgres://localhost/mydatabase' the database actually being used when I tested the db live, including migrating and seeding the database through knex commands, was 'postgres://localhost/username' - a database with the same name as the Owner of 'mydatabase'. But I think the mocha tests were trying to connect to mydatabase, which was still empty at that point, since the migrate and seed affected the the database 'username.'

So, I think this can be closed. I'll try to replicate the problem where I was connected to the wrong db; not sure how that could have happened, as I never intentionally set the connection, or any environment variable to 'postgres://localhost/username'.